# Maven 2 export jar to seperate directory

Tags: maven-2

I need to export all the compiled class files as a jar to a directory of a local testserver. I would like to let maven do this automatically.

```
<!-- Build instructions -->
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <defaultGoal>compile package</defaultGoal>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>/home/...</outputDirectory> <!--only class files go here, not the jar-->
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <includes>
                <include>plugin.yml</include>
            </includes>
            <directory>${basedir}</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

To build I first clean and then package via IntelliJ's Maven plugin. When I package I would like it to package the jarfile to my testserver so I don't have to move it over manually after every build.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Maven Ant plugin` to custom code what you want to after a particular goal:

- [Using Ant with Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-ant.html)
- [Ant Copt Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure maven-jar-plugin and configure its outputDirectory as per your requirements, you can see the details on this link.
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html